# Finding max in binarytree and return that node

Tags: java, search, find, binary-tree

As the title says I need help finding max in a binarytree. Im trying to do it with recursion.

The nodes have a instance variable of frequency which updates if the element in the node is a duplicate in the tree and it is that maximum value im trying to reach but I just get a nullpointerexception. this is my code:

```
private Node getMaxFreq(Node node){
    Node left = null;
    Node right = null;
    if(node == null){
        System.out.println("tree is empty");
    }
    if(node.compareTo(node.left) <= 0){
        getMaxFreq(node.left);
    }
    else{
         left = node;
    }
    if(node.compareTo(node.right) <= 0){
        getMaxFreq(node.right);
    }
    else{
        right = node;
    }

    if(left.compareTo(right) > 0){
        return left;
    }
    else{
        return right;
    }


}
/**
 * method to find the node with highest frequency in tree.
 * @return node with highest frequency.
 */
public void getMaxFreq(){
    Node temp = root;
    System.out.println(getMaxFreq(temp));
}

//Node class
public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    String word;
    int freq;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    Node(String word) {
        this.word = word;
        freq = 1;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return word + " occurs " + freq + " times.";
    }


    public int compareTo(Node other) {

        return Integer.compare(this.freq, other.freq);
    }

}
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Can you also post the Node class?

Comment: updated @user3747720

Answer (score 0):

add `return` statements in front of `getMaxFreq(node.left);` and other locations like that. I don't understand your code exactly but you never use your result of recursive calling. Maybe you should save them as variables and compare them with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for `null` before you use `left` and `right`. Eventually you **will** run into nodes who have no left, or right, or either. You need to check for that because of a left/right is null you — obviously — should not bother to examine or traverse to any such node, because there is no node there.

Comment: Could you evaluate a little bit more? im all stuck here.

Comment: @JohnBanana No, I cannot. This is all you need: before you try to use an object reference — like you for instance do in the line `if(left.compareTo(right) > 0){`— you **must** check that it is not `null`, or the program will throw the very exception you are getting.